# Rule violations prevent saving in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, rule

While debugging the edit of my usser information it is showing the esception of Rule violations prevent saving. Why this is? even I am checking values for all the compulsory fields, which set in DB as required. I am using asp.net MVC application with Linq to sql concept. I am trying to edit my user information record. how to get which validation is missing ? I saw a stack trace but , it showing only the line of db.SaveUpdates() , which sounds no information.

Comment: Any updates please ? even i have partial class of my user class.

Comment: helloooo...is some body alive there?